# How to fix Macbook trackpad's click feeling?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, click

For the past several days, I noticed that the trackpad on Macbook Pro does not move/press down when I click with my finger. Previously, when I used to click, I felt that the trackpad moved down by a tiny bit, e.g. around half a millimeter. But now, it does not.

I went to Trackpad settings and made sure that "Tap to click" is enabled. Restarting the computer did not fix the issue either.

How can I get it to work like before?

Comment: How old is the Macbook's battery? Impaired trackpad movement can be a symptom of a [swollen battery](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/What_to_do_with_a_swollen_battery), and indicates the battery has failed.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Mid-2015. However, there are no physical signs of swolen battery.

Comment: The inability of the trackpad to move downward could be a physical sign of a swollen battery: swollen enough to interfere with the trackpad, but not so swollen as to visibly (from the outside) deform the computer case. Source: this occurred on my MacBook Pro several years ago. Might be the same on yours.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica It might be, but then why it started to work after the solution provided in the answer?

Comment: I said it was a _possible_ cause, not the _only_ cause.  I did not see your statement in the Answer that it fixed the issue on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else has worked, try the following:

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Press and hold the following keys for at least 10 seconds (when computer is off):

   - Shift
   - Control
   - Option
   - Power key
3. Turn on the computer.

What I read is that this will reset the power grid and fix the issue. It did fix the issue on my Macbook Pro.

---

Source: [Apple Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7409623)

Comment: What model of Mac is this? Since 2015, the trackpad doesn't actually move at all -- it uses software controlled "haptic feedback" to give a sort of illusion of a click.

Comment: @benwiggy You are correct. Mine is of 2015.